Passport.js in Express.js doesn't work with Next.js
I recently stumbled into this problem while using Passport.js with Express Session. It would not save my session's user to the user.
I tried moving my middleware all around, but it didn't do much of a change. Here is my code:
server/src/index.js:
import express from 'express' ;
import session from 'express-session' ;
import passport from 'passport' ;
import mongoose from 'mongoose' ;
import cors from 'cors'
import routes from './routes/index.js' ;

const app = express() ;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080 ;
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
}

mongoose
  .connect("<db_location>")
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to DB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err)) ;

app.use(express.json()) ;
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) ;
app.use(cors(corsOptions)) ;
app.use(session({
  secret: "<secret>",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    httpOnly: false
  }
})) ;
app.use(routes) ;
app.use(passport.initialize()) ;
app.use(passport.session()) ;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port", PORT) ;
}) ;

server/src/routes/authRoutes.js:
import { Router } from "express" ;
import passport from "passport" ;
import '../strategies/local.js' ;
import { User } from "../models/User.js" ;

const authRouter = Router() ;

authRouter.get('/status', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session) ;
  return req.user 
    ? res.status(200).send(req.user)
    : res.sendStatus(400) ;
}) ;

authRouter.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  const { body: { username, displayName, password } } = req ;
  const newUser = new User({ username, displayName, password }) ;

  try {
    const savedUser = await newUser.save() ;

    return res.status(201).send(savedUser) ;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error) ;

    return res.sendStatus(400) ;
  }
}) ;

authRouter.post('/login', passport.authenticate("local"), (req, res) => {  
  return res.status(200).send(req.session.passport.user) ;
}) ;

authRouter.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user) return res.sendStatus(401) ;

  req.logout((err) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(400) ;

    return res.sendStatus(200) ;
  }) ;
}) ;

export { authRouter } ;

server/src/strategies/local.js:
import passport from 'passport' ;
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local' ;
import { User } from '../models/User.js' ;

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  return done(null, user._id) ;
}) ;

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const findUser = await User.findById(id) ;

    console.log('find user:', findUser) ;

    if (!findUser) throw new Error("Invalid Credentials.") ;

    return done(null, findUser) ;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('find user:', error) ;

    return done(error, null) ;
  }
}) ;

export default passport.use(new Strategy(async (username, password, done) => {
  try {
    const findUser = await User.findOne({ username }) ;

    if (!findUser || findUser.password !== password) throw new Error("Invalid Credentials.") ;

    return done(null, findUser) ;
  } catch (error) {
    return done(error, null) ;
  }
})) ;

client/src/components/LoginForm.tsx:
"use client"

import React, { useState } from "react" ;
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation" ;
import { UserType } from "@/types/types" ;

interface Props {
  baseUrl: string ;
}

const LoginForm = ({
  baseUrl 
}: Props) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState<Omit<UserType, "_id">>({
    username: '',
    displayName: '',
    password: ''
  }) ;
  const router = useRouter() ;

  function handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const { name, value } = e.target ;

    setFormData(prevData => {
      return {
        ...prevData,
        [name]: value
      }
    }) ;
  }

  async function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault() ;

    try {
      const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/auth/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      }) ;

      if (res.ok) {
        router.push("/") ;
        router.refresh() ;
      } else {
        console.log(res) ;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="w-full min-h-dvh p-2 flex flex-col">
      <input
        name="username"
        placeholder="Enter username..."
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="border-black border-2 rounded w-full p-2 bg-white outline-none text-black mb-1"
        value={formData.username}
      />

      <input
        name="password"
        placeholder="Enter password..."
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="border-black border-2 rounded w-full p-2 bg-white outline-none text-black mb-1"
        value={formData.password}
      />

      <button className="bg-white border-black border-2 rounded-lg py-2 px-3 text-black self-center mt-2 hover:bg-gray-200 active:bg-gray-300">Log In!</button>
    </form>
  ) ;
}

export default LoginForm ;

client/src/components/SignupForm.tsx:
"use client"

import React, { useState } from "react" ;
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation" ;
import { UserType } from "@/types/types" ;

interface Props {
  baseUrl: string ;
}

const SignupForm = ({
  baseUrl 
}: Props) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState<Omit<UserType, "_id">>({
    username: '',
    displayName: '',
    password: ''
  }) ;
  const router = useRouter() ;

  function handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const { name, value } = e.target ;

    setFormData(prevData => {
      return {
        ...prevData,
        [name]: value
      }
    }) ;
  }

  async function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault() ;

    try {
      console.log(formData)
      
      const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/auth/signup`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      }) ;

      console.log(res)

      if (res.ok) {
        router.push("/") ;
        router.refresh() ;
      } else {
        console.log(res) ;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="w-full min-h-dvh p-2 flex flex-col">
      <input
        name="username"
        placeholder="Enter username..."
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="border-black border-2 rounded w-full p-2 bg-white outline-none text-black mb-1"
        value={formData.username}
      />

      <input
        name="displayName"
        placeholder="Enter display name..."
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="border-black border-2 rounded w-full p-2 bg-white outline-none text-black mb-1"
        value={formData.displayName}
      />

      <input
        name="password"
        placeholder="Enter password..."
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="border-black border-2 rounded w-full p-2 bg-white outline-none text-black mb-1"
        value={formData.password}
      />

      <button className="bg-white border-black border-2 rounded-lg py-2 px-3 text-black self-center mt-2 hover:bg-gray-200 active:bg-gray-300">Sign Up!</button>
    </form>
  ) ;
}

export default SignupForm ;

client/src/lib/utils.ts:
export async function getStatus() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.SERVER_BASE_URL}/api/auth/status`) ;

  if (!res.ok) return 400 ;

  const data = await res.json() ;

  return data ;
}

